# UIButton as subview of MKAnnotationView not working

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm building a map app with MKMapView, and I can't seem to get interaction working in my subviews of MKAnnotationView.

I got a UIView class as the main subview of the MKAnnotationView and in there I have another subview, a UIButton, like this:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
//self.bringSubview(toFront: button)
//button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.addSubview(button)
```

(The commented lines don't seem to help)

Then the tapped function in the class looks like this:

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("button tapped:", sender)
}
```

Any idea why the buttonTapped() method would not fire?

Answer (score 0):

I think when mapkit adds your button to the map, it rasterizes it and adds it as a view. So the 'button' no longer reponds to touch events.

You can implement this using a tapGestureRecognizer.

When mapkit asks for view in the following function.
`func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

Use a Uiview with a tap gesture added to it.